# Did Rama or Krishna ever practise meditation?

Tags: krishna, rama, meditation

As per belief in Hinduism, both Rama and Krishna are incarnations of God and they really are beyond these material world things, and they probably had no reason for meditation(since they are symbols of perfections, the Supreme Being).

But through their incarnations, Rama and Krishna sets an example in front of man kind of ideal and correct way of living and basically drive people to follow the path of `Dharma`.

Now, it is well known how important meditation is for overall progress of individual. The term meditation may includes techniques designed to promote relaxation, build internal energy or life force and develop compassion, love, patience, generosity and forgiveness.

My Question is did Rama or Krishna ever practised the meditation to set as an example for man kind. Are there any scriptural references mentioning Rama or Krishna doing meditation?

Comment: Meditation is vague here. You mean Dhyana Yoga? Lakshma practised it and left his body. [Chapetr 106 of Uttarakanda](http://ramayana.tigercoder.com/template.php?c=07uttara). Not sure about Rama and Krishna. Some sources say Rama left his body same as Lakshmana. Even Lord Shiva does it most of the time. Even Vishnu but in Yoga Nidra.  I doubt whether Rama and Krishna done it for relaxation or something else.

Comment: @TheDestroyer `Meditation is vague here.` Yes, I agree and it was intentional. I could have used a more specific word like `dhyan` but its ok. the idea is to know if Rama or Krishna practised it in any form...

Comment: @WhisperingMonk: I assume Shri Rama did as Rishi Vashishtha instructs him on the same. As the text progresses, Shri Rama explains how he has changed. Although, I do not think he 'directly' mentions anywhere he meditated. Source: Yoga Vashishtha.

Comment: For Rama, refer [Yog Vasistha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Vasistha)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if he did it regularly, but on the night before Arjuna slayed Jayadratha, Krishna [went into](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07076.htm) a state of yoga and meditation:

> "Sanjaya said, 'Then lord Kesava, of eyes like lotus-petals, having entered the unrivalled mansion of Arjuna, touched water, and spread (for Arjuna) on the auspicious and even floor an excellent bed of Kusa blades that were of the hue of the lapis lazuli. And keeping excellent weapons around that bed, he adorned it duly with garlands of flowers and fried paddy, perfumes and other auspicious articles. And after Partha (also) had touched water, meek and submissive attendants brought the usual nightly sacrifice to the Three-eyed (Mahadeva). Then Partha, with a cheerful soul, having smeared Madhava with perfumes and adorned with floral garlands, presented unto Mahadeva the nightly offering.
>
> Then Govinda, with a faint smile, addressed Partha, saying, 'Blessed be thou, O Partha, lay thyself down, I leave thee.' Placing door-keepers then, and also sentinels well-armed, blessed Kesava, followed by (his charioteer) Daruka, repaired to his own tent.
>
> He then laid himself down on his white bed, and thought of diverse measures to be adopted. And the illustrious one (Kesava) of eyes like lotus petals, began for Partha's sake, to think of various means that would dispel (Partha's) grief and anxiety and enhance his prowess and splendour.
>
> Of soul wrapt in yoga, that Supreme Lord of all, viz., Vishnu of wide-spread fame, who always did what was agreeable to Jishnu, **desirous of benefiting (Arjuna), lapsed into yoga, and meditation.**
>
> There was none in the Pandava camp who slept that night.

What [happens next](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07077.htm) is really interesting. Arjuna, despite his anxiety, falls asleep in his tent and Krishna takes Arjuna (in Arjuna's dream) to Shiva's abode to seek his blessings:

> Endued with great energy, his body seemed to be flaming with a thousand eyes. **And he was seated with Parvati** and many creatures of brilliant forms (around him). And his attendants were engaged in singing and playing upon musical instruments, in laughing and dancing, in moving and stretching their hands, and In uttering loud shouts.
>
> ... And Krishna and Arjuna said, 'We bow to Bhava, to Sarva, to Rudra, to the boon-giving deity. We bow to the lord of all creatures endued with life, to the god who is always fierce, to him who is called Kapardin! **We bow to Mahadeva, to Bhima, to the Three-eyed**, to him who is peace and contentment. We bow to Isana, to him who is the destroyer of (Daksha's) sacrifice. Let salutations be to the slayer of Andhaka, to the father of Kumara, to him who is of blue throat, to him who is the creator.'

Arjuna [gets the indication](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07078.htm) that his vow (of slaying Jayadratha) will be soon accomplished:

> ... And the god also granted him the terrible Pasupata weapon and the accomplishment of his vow. Then having thus once more obtained the Pasupata weapon from the supreme god, **the invincible Arjuna, with hair standing on end, regarded his business to be already achieved.** Then Arjuna and Krishna filled with joy, paid their adorations unto the great god by bowing their heads. And permitted by Bhava both Arjuna and Kesava, those two heroes, almost immediately came back to their own camp, filled with transports of delight. Indeed, their joy was as great as that of Indra and Vishnu when those two gods, desirous of slaying Jambha, obtained the permission of Bhava that slayer of great Asuras.'"

And towards the end of Mahabharata, before deciding to give up his body too, Krishna [was](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16004.htm) apparently in a state of yoga:

> Conversant with the truth of every topic, Vasudeva, though he was the Supreme Deity, wished to die, for dispelling all doubts and establishing a certainty of results (in the matter of human existence), simply for upholding the three worlds and for making the words of Atri’s son true. Having restrained all his senses, speech, and mind, **Krishna laid himself down in high Yoga**.

When Krishna goes to Hastinapura as an emissary and stays at Vidura's place, he [also sets](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05094.htm) other examples like how should one start the day:

> And rising from bed, Janardana of Dasarha's race, that bull amongst all the Sattwatas, went through all the customary acts of the morning. **And having cleansed himself by a bath, recited the sacred Mantras and poured libations of clarified butter on the sacrificial fire. Madhava decked his person and began to worship the rising sun**. And while the unvanquished Krishna of Dasarha's race was still engaged in his morning devotions, Duryodhana and Suvala's son Sakuni came to him and said, 'Dhritarashtra is seated in his court, with all the Kurus headed by Bhishma and with all the kings of the earth. They are all soliciting thy presence, O Govinda...

---

Rama also sincerely [meditated](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga6/ayodhya_6_frame.htm) on Lord Narayana the day before his coronation ceremony:

> After Vasistha left, Rama took bath and meditated on Lord Narayana with undistracted mind along with his wide-eyed wife, Seetha. [2-6-1]
>
> Taking the vessel with clarified butter on his head as per scriptures, he offered to Lord Vishnu the clarified butter, by dropping it into the blazing fire. [2-6-2]
>
> Rama ate the remainder of clarified butter after finishing the sacrifice, which he performed for his own good, **silently meditated on Lord Narayana with controlled mind** and slept along with Seetha on a properly laid bed of Kusa grass in a splendid temple of Lord Vishnu. [2-6-3, 2-6-4]

Comment: I guess this is enough evidence to conclude that they both did some form of meditations!

Answer (score 4):

Lord Krishna said he preformed severe austerities to obtain Pradyumna as his son.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10012.htm

> That son whom I obtained through ascetic penances and observances of austere brahmacarya for twelve years on the breast of Himavati whither I had gone for the purpose, that son of mine, Pradyumna, of great energy and a portion of Sanat-kumara himself, begotten by me upon my wife Rukmini who had practised vows as austere as mine, that hero even never solicited this best of objects, this unrivalled discus, which thou of little understanding had solicited!

---

He did penance to obtain Samba also.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a015.htm

> "The blessed Krishna said, 'Bowing my head with great joy unto that mass of energy and effulgence, I said these words unto the great Deity, with a heart filled with gladness,--Firmness in virtue, the slaughter of foes in battle, the highest fame, the greatest might, devotion to Yoga, thy adjacence, and hundreds upon hundreds of children, these are the boons I solicit of thee,--So be it,--said Sankara repeating the words I had uttered. After this, the mother of the universe, the upholders of all things, who cleanses, all things, viz., the spouse of Sarva, that vast receptacle of penances said with a restrained soul these words unto me,--'The puissant Mahadeva has granted thee, O sinless one, **a son who shall be named Samva.**

Answer (score 3):

Lord Krishna meditated upon Himself daily in Brahma muhurta period.

> Texts 4-5: Lord Mādhava would rise during the brāhma-muhūrta period
> and touch water. **With a clear mind He would then meditate upon
> Himself**, the single, self-luminous, unequaled and infallible Supreme
> Truth, known as Brahman, who by His very nature ever dispels all
> contamination, and who through His personal energies, which cause the
> creation and destruction of this universe, manifests His own pure and
> blissful existence.
>
> ~[Srimad Bhagavatam , 10th Canto, Chapter 70](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/70/)

Comment: what happens if you delete a post and then undelete it

Comment: @Funlife don't spam random places for your points. If you look for points then answer as many as questions. Per answer you get more points than per question

Answer (score 2):

For Krishna, [Srimad Bhagvatam Canto 10:Chapter 70](http://bhagavata.org/canto10/chapter70.html)

> (4-5) Mâdhava rose during the brâhma-muhûrta [the
>   hour before sunrise], touched water and cleared **His mind to meditate
>   upon the unequaled, exclusive, self-luminous Self beyond all dullness
>   of matter.** This True Self dispels, infallible as it is, by its [His]
>   own nature perpetually the impurity and gives the joy of existence. **It
>   is known as the Brahman that, with its [His] energies, constitutes the
>   cause of the creation and the destruction of this universe** [see also
>   3.29: 31 & 36-37, B.G. 7: 5 & 6 and *]. (6) After according to the vidhi having bathed in pure water, He, the most truthful One, first
>   dressing in lower and upper garments, performed the entire sequence of
>   the worship at dawn and such and then, after offering oblations in the
>   fire, quietly controlling His speech, chanted the Vedic mantra [the
>   Gâyatrî, see also **].

For Rama, [Yoga Vashishta  Book 7:Chapter 194](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc228891.html)

> 43. **He sits reclined in the immensity of Brahman**, with his enlightened view of the visibles as subsisting in Him; he remains indifferent to
>       all things, and devoid of his desire for anything, and sits quiet in
>       the quiescence of his liberation; which is styled as moksha by the
>       wise.

Answer (score 2):

Parnasala is a small village located near Bhadrachalam in the state of Telangana. It is believed that Lord ShriRama spent some of his fourteen years of exile at this place. Ramayana says, During that period Lakshmana setup a small house in parnasala and he uses dharbha to cover the ceiling portion of the house. He creates a dharbhasana for Rama to perform meditation. [Here is the reference](http://sitaramaswamy.com/bhadrachalam-parnasala.html)

Comment: Hi, please add reference which supports your answer. Please check [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/6981)

Comment: http://www.sitaramaswamy.com/bhadrachalam-parnasala.html

Comment: Please add the link in the answer itself by editing.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Thanks for guiding me. Will add the link along with the answer.

Comment: Happy to see you have done it. Also use the better formats like if you are copy pasting any verse then put it as quote and use bold or italic for important points.

Comment: Sure, will do that in upcoming posts.